# Aliasing problem when transforming a smart object in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

As you can see in the above image, I am trying to rotate this photo, which has been converted to a smart object.

However, the edges are looking like a zigzag. How can I fix this?

Comment: You should try out different Image Interpolations (`Preferences > General`). After changing Photoshop to a different Interpolation Method you just have to click the Transformation Handle on your Smart Object and confirming the Transformation without actually making one.

Answer (score 5):

### Try this FIRST:

1. Go to preferences > general and change the "image interpolation" to
   "bilinear."
2. Then select the smartobject with the bad antialiasing and then
   activate the transform tool as if you were going to scale it, but do
   NOT scale it.
3. Even though you haven't transformed anything, confirm the
   transformation by pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key or by clicking the
   checkmark symbol up in the transform function's context menu.
4. The antialiasing of the smartobject should now have changed and may
   be satisfactory for your purposes.

**If the results are NOT satisfactory**

### Try this NEXT:

Rotation *and* scaling all in "one go" may be too much for the anti-aliasing engine in older PS versions to handle and produces the artifacts you mention.

Here is a workaround that admittedly requires you making two "nested" smartobjects (one inside another), so it's definitely a workaround, but it does produce good results, remains fully editable, and does not resort to destructive methods like rasterizing:

1. Create a smartobject from scratch and rotate it to the desired angle
   but DO NOT scale it down yet.
2. Out of this rotated smartobject create a new smartobject.
3. Scale this new one down to the desired size and there should be no
   artifacts.

You may also try scaling first and then rotating, but if you scale down to under 40%, create a new smart object and then rotate, you may still get artifacts. I don't know why the order makes a difference, it just does.

By the way, this is also the way to go if you are putting a **perspectival distortion on a smartobject**. FIRST distort, make into new smartobject, THEN scale down.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign! I cleaned up some of the formatting of your answer to make it a little more readable

Comment: Merci for the reformatting, Zach.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, by Pen tool draw outlines over photograph, then create new layer, then make selection, then go to edit and click on stroke, keep stroke of 3 or 4 with white color, your problem will solve

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with PS CC 19.0, but the solutions above didn’t work for me.

In the end, I copied and pasted the layers (a new feature) from my smart object (which where originally embedded PSDs) into the main Photoshop file and scaled them down to match. I then added any effects that were added to the smart objects onto my new layer.

This solved the issue for me.